# Allowing access to protected member function for class outside of namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++17, friend, forward-declaration

Consider the following code:

```
namespace A
{
  class B
  {
  protected:
    friend class C;
    static void foo();
  };
}

class C
{
public:
  C() { A::B::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
  C c;
  return 0;
}
```

As currently constructed, this code will not compile - the friendship declared in `class B` applies to a (currently non-existent) `A::C`, and not the `C` in the global namespace. How can I work around this effectively, assuming I cannot add `C` to non-global namespace? I have tried using `friend class ::C;`, but the compiler does not like that. I have also tried forward declaring `class C;` before the `namespace A` scope, but that does not appear to work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a forward declaration for class `C` worked for me, what compiler are you using?

```
class C;

namespace A
{
  class B
  {
  protected:
    friend class ::C;
    static void foo();
  };
}

// ...
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RAT4Al70x7bFyBpl)

---

**Edit:** as Vlad points out, both `friend C` and `friend ::C` also work, provided you have that forward declaration in place.  But `friend class C` doesn't, I'll pass that one over to the language lawyers.

Comment: Hm.. I tried one or the other, somehow did not think to try both at the same time... I.e., I forward declared `C`, and I did a `friend class ::C` separately, but not together

Comment: Ah well, what can I say? :)

Answer (score 1):

The class C firstly is declared in the class B within namespace A. That is within the namespace A there is introduced the class C due to the elaborated type specifier and there is no previous declaration of the class.

The class C declared in the global namespace is a different class.

You need at first to declare the class C in the global namespace as

```
class C;
namespace A
{
    class B
    {
    protected:
        friend class C;
        static void foo() {
            std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
        }
    };
}

class C
{
public:
    C() { A::B::foo(); }
};
```

In this case there is no need to use the elaborated type specifier

```
friend class C;
```

You could just write

```
friend C;
```

Otherwise without the forward declaration of the class C in the global namespace you need to declare the class C in the namespace A like

```
namespace A
{
    class B
    {
    protected:
        friend class C;
        static void foo() {
            std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
        }
    };
}

namespace A
{
    class C
    {
    public:
        C() { B::foo(); }
    };
}
```

And in main you need to write

```
A::C c;
```

Comment: `friend class C;` in `A::B` means `A::C` even if `::C` exists: friend declarations are weird that way.